# Compare column values from different tables based on condition

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
table1 
column1 column2
code1    abc 
code1    xyz
code1    pqr
code2    abc
code2    xyz
code2    fgh

table2
column1 coulmn2
abc      false
xyz      false
pqr      false
fgh      true
```

now I want to retrieve the data of different code values from table1 which has value as false,

I tried joining two tables but I'm not getting desired result

```
select distinct t.coumn1
from table1 t join table2 t2 on t.coulmn2 = t2.cloumn1
where t2.culmn2 = false;
```

but I'm getting both code1 and code2 as result, need help in find out the right query

Comment: Can you provide the output you're expecting. If I look at your table and explanation it seems like you SHOULD be getting code1 and code2 as responses. Ignoring all other values in table2, table2 has 'abc' as false, and table1 has code1/abc AND code2/abc pairings. In this way it's guaranteed for you query to return code1 and code2.

Comment: my out put should be 'code1'

Comment: That answer doesn't make sense though. Table 2 has a pairing of abc|false and table 1 has code1|abc AND code2|abc. Considering your data you should get code1 and code2. Either your data is incorrect or there's some part of the question you're asking that I still don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using not exists

```
select distinct t.column1
from table1 t
where not exists (
   select 1 
   from table1 t1
   join table2 t2
     on t1.column1 = t.column1 and t2.column1 = t1.column2 and t2.column2 <> 'false');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f5dd265366b38a90d0da25eee961215c)

Comment: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select" , I'm getting this error

Comment: @user2108383,  sorry, misprint is corrected

Comment: still I'm getting code2 as out put :( , I should get out as only code1 bcz for code2 I have 'fgh' which has a value of true

Comment: @user2108383, .. corrected. See the fiddle also.